# How to change button automatically as 'start' to 'expired' based on time difference of hours and minutes using JavaScript by using setInterval?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on code using PHP and JavaScript (`test.php`), in that there's the `setInterval` code, which will run for **every 1 second** and will check time using PHP and compare it with DB defined, which I have defined manually.

So after start time, the button should get start and if time has completed, then it should show expired. Let's say the start time is (13:02) i.e ("hours":"minutes") and the end time is local time, which is getting from PHP.

So suppose end/current time is("14":"03") means expired button will call automatically but I am getting only the start button and every second this script will run, but still it is not changing the start button to expired.

Below I have written my code:

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
  setInterval(function() {
    var start_tym = "<?php echostrtotime("13: 22")?>";
    var cur_tym = "<?php 
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    echo strtotime(date("H:i"))
      ?> ";
    var chkchk = start_tym - cur_tym;

    if ((chkchk) > (-3600)) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ' <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="myfunction()">Start</button>';
    } else if ((chkchk) < (-3600)) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ' <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="myfunction()">Expired</button>';
    }
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: clearinterval(x) ? what is x here? if you assign setInterval to x then you can clear it

Comment: @ABUdhay by mistake i have written clearinterval(x) no use as of now

Comment: in negative integer the greater value will be lower for eg. -5000 will be smaller than -3600 ? so please check the condition

Comment: @ABUdhay yes i know that,  based on negative answer I have  placed condition ut still it's not working.

Comment: @abudhay can you please check this code in by creating test.php file and tell me where i need to improve so i will get perfect solution

Comment: have you checked with only else instead ifelse? i need more info like logs and all

Comment: What about conversion string to number? I mean variables start_tym and cur_tym

Comment: @ABUdhay yes  it will check if one condition not satisfy then will come to else block

Comment: I don't know, but have you taken into account, that embedded PHP code will not change? You need to pressing F5 key to refresh page to update embedded PHP code, and this also causes "reloading" JS.
And note also that setInterval will have same constant values of variables start_tym and cur_tym, which cause choosing only one if